# Simple python / Beautiful Soup type question

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do some simple string manipulation with the href attribute of a hyperlink extracted using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="http://www.some-site.com/">Some Hyperlink</a>')
href = soup.find("a")["href"]
print href
print href[href.indexOf('/'):]
```

All I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print href[href.indexOf('/'):]
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'indexOf'
```

How should I convert whatever `href` is into a normal string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python strings do not have an `indexOf` method.

Use `href.index('/')`

`href.find('/')` is similar. But `find` returns `-1` if the string is not found, while `index` raises a `ValueError`.

So the correct thing is to use `index` (since '...'[-1] will return the last character of the string).

Comment: Also worth noting a Unicode string will have all the same methods a regular string does

Answer (score 0):

href is a unicode string. If you need the regular string, then use

```
regular_string = str(href)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean find(), not indexOf().

[Python docs on strings](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html).